# Can we create 3D buffers around point data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, 3d

I have multiple point data with lat, long, and elevation.
I want to create a 3D buffer on one set of points and check for intersection another set of points.
I am using Qgs2threejs for visualization.
How can we do this in QGIS?

Comment: By 3D buffer did you mean a spherical buffer or a "flat buffer" where each vertices has the same z value as the point ? Also are you sure you need buffer, Qgs2threejs let you visualise point as sphere, cylinder or other shape (the radius/size could be fixed or expression based)

Comment: I want to create a spherical buffer on all points. I understand that 3D buffer is not available in QGIS. But do we have any python package which allows us to create such buffer?

Answer (score 5):

While I am not aware of a plugin which creates spheres (even if it should not be too difficoult to write), I would suggest you investigate a different, possibly more elegant route.

Instead of creating a 3D buffer around your points just to check if these buffers contain/intersect a(nother?) set of points, you could use `ST_3DDWithin`, a PostgreSQL/PostGIS function.

## ST_3DDWithin

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DDWithin.html

> ST_3DDWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid);

Or maybe `ST_3DDFullyWithin` if you want to check geometries which are more complex than the basic 3D points.